# Discord bot not reacting to its message but errors thrown in the console, whats going on? discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am developing a bot for my school server and people can get very annoying there which is why i am trying to make a timeout commands where users can vote for someone to be timed out.

I have used `await message.add_reaction(emoji = vote)` but for some reason the bot is not reacting nor sending an error to the console.

This is my code, defining the command and error handler:

```
@bot.tree.command(name = 'timeout_vote', description = 'vote for someone to be timed out')
@app_commands.checks.has_any_role('verified')
@app_commands.describe(timeout = 'Person you want to vote on to timeout')
async def timeout_vote(interaction: discord.Interaction, timeout: discord.Member, reason: str = 'No reason given'):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = 'TIMEOUT VOTE', description = '')
  embed.set_author(name = timeout.name, icon_url = timeout.display_avatar)
  embed.add_field(name = 'Member being voted on:', value = timeout.mention, inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = 'Responsible vote executer:', value = interaction.user.mention, inline = False)
  if timeout.display_avatar == None:
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = interaction.avatar.url)
  else:
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = timeout.display_avatar)
  vote = 'U+2705'
  message = await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed)
  await message.add_reaction(emoji = vote)

@timeout_vote.error
async def timeout_vote_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingAnyRole):
    await bot.get_channel(1106325554942197992).send(content = 'You must be verified to complete this command')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your error handler will suppress any errors other than `app_commands.MissingAnyRole`, which is why nothing is being displayed in the terminal. I recommend adding an `else` to raise unhandled errors:

```py
@timeout_vote.error
async def timeout_vote_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingAnyRole):
    await bot.get_channel(1106325554942197992).send(content='You must be verified to complete this command')
  else:
    raise error
```

I believe that the error being generated is related to the fact that the method `InteractionResponse.send_message()` does not return anything.
If you want to get the message sent as a response from an interaction, consider using [Interaction.original_response()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.original_response):

```py
await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
message = await interaction.original_response()
```